# copy the names of DNA sequences in a phylogenetic tree file and add the names of the species to it?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

From a file looking like this one :

> (AJirio:0.00230,(AJama.1.1:0.00171,(AJkago.1:0.00057,AJtok:0.00033)1.00    :0.00080)0.94:0.00085,Atab.1.1.1:0.27697);

I need to obtain this file :

> ```
> AJirio"AJirio"  
> AJama.1.1"AJama"
> AJkago.1"AJkago"
> AJtok"AJtok"
> Atab.1.1.1"Atab"
> ```

So basically extract the name of the DNA sequences in a phylogenetic tree and add the name of the species (AJirio, AJkama..) with quotation marks to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

**`Awk`** approach:

```
awk -v RS=',' -F':' '{ 
       sub(/\(*/, ""); dna = $1;
       gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "", $1);
       printf "%s\042%s\042\n", dna, $1 
}' file
```

---

**`sed`** approach:

```
sed -En 's/\(*?(([a-zA-Z]+)[^:]*):[^,]+/\1"\2"/g; s/,/\n/gp' file
```

---

The output:

```
AJirio"AJirio"
AJama.1.1"AJama"
AJkago.1"AJkago"
AJtok"AJtok"
Atab.1.1.1"Atab"
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working on this file but in most of my files I have more parenthesis. For example :   ((((AJirio.1.1 will become     (((AJirio.1.1"AJirio"  And I would like to have AJirio.1.1"AJirio".  Do you know how to modify your script to have this?

Comment: @DavidB, yes, use my update